# Is an Abelian topological group compact if it is complete and Bohr-compact?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

A topological group $G$ will be called *Bohr-compact* if its Bohr topology (i.e., the largest precompact group topology) is compact and Hausdorff.

A topological group $G$ is Bohr-compact if it admits an injective continuous homomorphism $h:G\to H$ into a compact topological group and for each continuous homomorphism $h:G\to K$ into a compact topological group $K$ the image $h(G)$ is compact.

By the classical result of van der Waerden (1933), for every $n\in\mathbb N$ the group $SO(2n+1)$ endowed with the discrete topology is Bohr-compact. This shows that non-compact complete Bohr-compact topological groups do exist. Can such a group be Abelian?

**Problem.** *Is each (complete) Bohr-compact Abelian topological group compact?*

**Remark.** It can be shown that an Abelian topological group $G$ is compact if and only if it is Bohr-compact and locally K-analytic (i.e., contains a K-analytic neighborhood of zero). So, a counterexample to the Problem (if exists) neccessarily is bad in the sense of Descriptive Set Theory (its construction should essentially use Axiom of Choice).

We recall that a topological space $X$ is *K-analytic* if $X$ is the image of a Polish space under an upper-semicontinuous compact-valued function.